# Differential equation question

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, rocket-science

I've been seeing those formulas and I couldn't exactly know how to explain them formally.

$$f_{ext}\Delta t=m\Delta v+ \Delta m\Delta v-\Delta m V$$
thus
$$f_{ext}=m\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}+ \Delta m \frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}-\frac{ m}{\Delta t} v= m\frac{dv}{dt}-\frac{dm}{dt}v$$
as $\Delta t\rightarrow 0$.

My question was that: where did the term $\Delta m \frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$ go?

Similiar $(m+dm)(v+vd)=mv+mdv+dmv$ where did $dmdv$ go?
I thought it might has something to do with both $\Delta m \Delta v$ approach $0$, but why can't $\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$ approach infinity faster than $\Delta m$ approach $0$?

Comment: This question is lacking context. Please add further information about the context so that potential answerers will know exactly what the issue here is. For instance, you should explain what the symbols denote (even though one can guess it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Delta v/\Delta t$ is the average acceleration over the short time $\Delta t$.  Physically this should be (possibly large but) finite as infinite accelerations are not physical.  When multiplied by the very small $\Delta m$, the product is comparatively much smaller than the other terms.

Technically, when one uses differentials, a term like $dm\times dv$ is a "higher order infinitesimal".  In manipulating differentials, only the lowest order infinitesimals are kept.

---

Edit: If you take a step back you can write
\begin{align}
f_{ext}\Delta t &= \Delta p= (m+\Delta m)(v+\Delta v)- mv\, ,\\
&= mv\left(1+\frac{\Delta m}{m}\right)\left(1+\frac{\Delta v}{v}\right) -mv\, ,
\\
&=mv\left(\frac{\Delta m}{m}+\frac{\Delta m}{m} \frac{\Delta v}{v}+\frac{ \Delta v}{v}\right) \,  
\tag{1} 
\end{align}
In this form, it is clear that what matters is the size of $\frac{\Delta v}{v}$ and $\frac{\Delta m}{m}$.  For small $\Delta t$, both $\Delta m/m$ and $\Delta v/v$ should be quite small - say $10^{-6}$ so that the first and last terms of (1) are of size $10^{-6}$ while the middle term is of size $10^{-12}$ and so ignored.  (Formally, for arbitrary small $\Delta m/m$ and $\Delta v/v$, the middle term is way smaller than the other two.

It may be that, for some reason, $\Delta m/m$ is NOT small... it could be -say - of size (1).  If this is the case then the last two terms are still of size $\Delta v/v\sim 10^{-6}$ and then you would throw those two terms out.  Clearly however, when one or more such ratios are NOT small, one has to make a special argument.

Comment: so the reason we ignored $\Delta m \frac{\Delta V}{\Delta t}$ here was because it's a physics problem, and we were actually doing an estimation?

Comment: in principle these quantities are small but a ratio like $\Delta A/\Delta B$ has a finite value.  Here, there is nice physics to explain why such a ratio shoukd be finite.

Comment: That's the magic of calculus - if you do it properly then the estimates become exact. In this case, the "ignored" term goes to zero.

Comment: @SeanE.Lake amen to that!

Comment: Thanks! Just in case: if $\Delta A/ \Delta B$ doesn't have a finite value, then we could not assume this, right?

Comment: @JC added material to answer your comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$, then $\Delta m\rightarrow 0$ and $\Delta v\rightarrow 0$ also. This means that terms with two or more infinitesimal (like $\Delta m\Delta v$) will become negligible beside terms with only one infinitesimal as each terms goes to 0. Thus, they can be left out from the equation.